# Apache2 and mysql authorization

Tags: mysql, apache2, authorization

I'm trying to setup authorization on apache2 on Ubuntu 14.04 using MySQL.

.htaccess:

```
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
AuthUserFile /dev/null

AuthMySQL On
AuthMySQL_Authoritative on
AuthMySQL_Host 10.30.200.1
AuthMySQL_Username name
AuthMySQL_Password pass
AuthMySQL_DB db
AuthMySQL_Password_Table access
AuthMySQL_Username_Field user
AuthMySQL_Password_Field password
AuthMySQL_Encryption_Types PHP_MD5
AuthMySQL_Empty_Passwords Off

Require valid-user
```

If credentials is right I receive 401 error and  "[:error] [pid 1763] No requires line available" in error.log. Else - just 401.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: same problem here, will report back if i manage to find a solution

Comment: It has work for me on apache2.4 and ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any patches turning off AuthMySQL_Authoritative and doing AuthMySQL_Where solved the problem completely.

Answer (score 2):

Had the exact same problem on the same versions.

Setting the following on the `.htaccess`, did the trick for me:
`set AuthMySQL_Authoritative Off`

Answer (score 0):

The error message comes from the mod-auth-mysql module itself.
I downloaded the source and took a look in the mod_auth_mysql.c file

With the function mysql_check_auth() near the end of the file you can find this:

```
    if (!reqs_arr) {
    if (sec->authoritative) {
        APACHELOG(APLOG_ERR, r, "No requires line available");
        return HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED;
    } else {
        return DECLINED;
    }
}
```

After some research i found this site and the following patch:

http://ehealth-aussie.blogspot.de/2013/07/compiling-modauthmysqlso-under-mountain.html

http://sourceforge.net/p/modauthmysql/patches/13/

But the ubuntu/debian module is based on version 2.2.0 and not 3.0.0.
Also parts of the patch are already included:
mod-auth-mysql_4.3.9-13.1ubuntu3.diff.gz

**// EDIT**

First you must set AuthMySQL_Authoritative Off in order to let handle mod_authz_user the requires, like valid-user.


If you want to check the group via mod-auth-mysql a simple fix is moving the user and group requirements in the AuthMySQL_Where declaration because ap_requires does not exist anymore and the patch sets it to Null:

```
require group g1 g2
```

This becomes:

```
AuthMySQL_Where "AND user_group IN ('g1', 'g2')"
```